# What does js Array.prototype.copyWithin(target, start,end) do when called on an object literal?

Tags: javascript

This is from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin):

```
[].copyWithin.call({length: 5, 3: 1}, 0, 3);
// {0: 1, 3: 1, length: 5}
```

My confused misunderstanding:
Where does the property 0:1 come from? The non-array object with 2 properties will have values from the 4th on copied into the 0th on location so noop. The output is a reversal and a new property {0:1}

Comment: It's hard to understand what you find confusing when you read the documentation.

Comment: @FelixKling The answers make it clear. I was just not thinking about index values for properties.

Comment: "*will have values from the 4th on copied into the 0th on location*" - yes exactly. Notice that `3: 1` *is* the 4th location. Not sure why you think that would be a noop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's remember that standard arrays are just objects with special handling of properties whose names are [array indexes](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-type)*, a special `length` property, and the `Array.prototype` as their prototype. Array indexes are property names (we write them as numbers, but technically, at a specification level, they're *strings* — naturally, implementations optimize them, though).

We can use `copyWithin` on a non-array object because it's "intentionally generic" — it doesn't check that it's being called on an array, so long as the object it's called on has a `length` property.

Your original object, `{length: 5, 3: 1}`, has two properties: `"length"` (value 5) and `"3"` (value 1). Then the `copyWithin(obj, 0, 3)` call is made, which says "Copy the entries starting with index 3 through the end of the 'array' to index 0." So **very** roughly:

```
var target = 0;
var source = 3;
while (source < obj.length) {
    if (source in obj) {           // If the object has this property...
        obj[target] = obj[source]; // ...copy it
    }
    ++target;
    ++source;
}
```

So it ends up copying property `"3"` (value 1) to property `"0"`, then moving on to property `"4"`, which doesn't exist and so is skipped, and then stopping because `source` isn't `< obj.length` anymore.

You may find it useful to read through [MDN's polyfill for `copyWithin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin) and [the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.copywithin) to get a good idea what it does.

---

* From that link:

> An *integer index* is a String-valued property key that is a canonical numeric String (see 7.1.16) and whose numeric value is either +0 or a positive integer ≤ 2<sup>53</sup>-1. An *array index* is an *integer index* whose numeric value *i* is in the range +0 ≤ i < 2<sup>32</sup>-1.

Comment: My questions already been answered, but also: the reversal of the other two properties is because the enumeration of properties must not be ordered in object literals I guess?

Comment: @user135711 What do you mean by "reversal"?

Comment: @user135711: There's no reversal. My original answer wasn't as clear as it should have been, I've improved it. `copyWithin(obj, 0, 3)` says to copy properties starting at "index" 3 to "index" 0, and then to continue with the next indexes (4 and 1), while the source index is `<` the `length` property of the target (since no `end` argument was supplied).

Answer (score 4):

Your source array-like object is roughly equivalent to the following array:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, 1, undefined]
```

(length of 5, and 1 at index 3)

`copyWithin` copies what's at index 3 to index 0.

That's exactly what happens here.

From the documentation:

> arr.copyWithin(target, start)
>
> target Zero based index at which to copy the sequence to. If negative,
>   target will be counted from the end.
>
> start Optional Zero based index at which to start copying elements
>   from. If negative, start will be counted from the end.

Comment: And why does it have a value of 1? There's more to it than that. It would be a no op on an array.

Comment: @user135711: Because the value of property `3` is `1`? What else should it be?